Configurable Widget not working in Swift Package
My iOS App has two static widgets. The code for the widgets resides in a library that is part of a Swift Package, imported into the main project.
The two static widgets work as expected, but if I add a configurable widget, following the same approach, this one does not work and only displays the placeholder view.
In more detail, in the widget extension, I have the following code for the two static widgets:
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import ItemWidgetsKit

@main
struct ItemWidgetsBundle: WidgetBundle {
    var body: some Widget {
        RecentSavesWidget()
        RecommendationsWidget()
    }
}

the rest of the code, including the two Widget implementations, the TimelineProvider, etc, are in the imported ItemsWidgetKit, which is the aforementioned library part of a Swift Package. These two widgets work as expected.
To add a configurable widget, the code above changes like so:
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import ItemWidgetsKit

@main
struct ItemWidgetsBundle: WidgetBundle {
    @WidgetBundleBuilder var body: some Widget {
        makeWidgets()
    }

    func makeWidgets() -> some Widget {
        if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
            return WidgetBundleBuilder.buildBlock(RecentSavesWidget(), TopicRecommendationsWidget())
        } else {
            return WidgetBundleBuilder.buildBlock(RecentSavesWidget(), RecommendationsWidget())
        }
    }
}

TopicRecommendationsWidget is similar to RecommendationsWidget except that it lets you choose a topic to display recommendations for, by long pressing and selecting an intent. It uses the same logic as RecommendationsWidget to read data from a file, written by the main app.
I followed the same approach of the other two widgets, and put the code inside ItemWidgetsKit This time, though, the widget does not work, and it only loads the placeholder; in fact, in the AppIntentTimelineProvider implementation (see below) only placeholder(in:) gets ever called
@available(iOS 17.0, *)
public struct TopicTimelineProvider: AppIntentTimelineProvider {
    public func placeholder(in context: Context) -> TopicEntry {
        return TopicEntry(date: Date(), content: TopicContent.sampleContent)
    }

    public func snapshot(for configuration: TopicIntent, in context: Context) async -> TopicEntry {
        return TopicEntry(date: Date(), content: configuration.topicEntity.topic)
    }

    public func timeline(for configuration: TopicIntent, in context: Context) async -> Timeline<TopicEntry> {
        let entry = TopicEntry(date: Date(), content: configuration.topicEntity.topic)

      return Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .never)
    }
}

for more context, here's the code for the configurable Widget implementation (that resides inside ItemWidgetsKit
@available(iOS 17.0, *)
public struct TopicRecommendationsWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String

    public init() {
        self.kind = WidgetKind.topicRecommendations // a string stored elsewhere
    }

    public var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        AppIntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: TopicIntent.self, provider: TopicTimelineProvider()) { entry in
            TopicWidgetContainerView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("New Recommendations")
        .description("Select a Topic")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemMedium, .systemLarge])
    }
}

if I move the code out of the Swift Package and add it directly to the widget extension target, then it works as expected, but this would disrupt the existing architecture.
Any Idea why this happens and what would be the solution to this problem? Thank you

I've been seeing something similar in my own app. Looks like iOS is unable to resolve intents from Swift Packages. Check Console.app and look at messages from chronod, you might see something like 'Unable to resolve default intent'. I'll swing back here if I find a solution myself.
